# How can I change $type during serialization in JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, json.net

Duplicate of [Using a custom type discriminator to tell JSON.net which type of a class hierarchy to deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099466/using-a-custom-type-discriminator-to-tell-json-net-which-type-of-a-class-hierarc/12203624#12203624)

and [JsonConverter how to deserialize to generic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325664/jsonconverter-how-to-deserialize-to-generic-object/35349393#35349393)

Thx https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc

Consumer application knows Class A, I will serve Class B that inherited from Class A.Class B is defined in server application.

```
public class A {} // Both Application know it
public class B:A{} // It is defined in Server Application
public A GetAInstanceById(){ // It is written in Server Application, but both application know its method signature, consumer application calls it by simple Web Call
   ..............
   return new B();
}
```

B response is  serialized by JsonConvert.SerializeObject method, with this settings.

`settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;`

When consumer application get the response from server application, it tries to deserialize response to A (because of method signature)

Json.Net could not find B class and convert instance as "object" and throw "object Must Implement IConvertible" exception.

So I want to serialize response as $type:"A" . How can I change $type:"B" to $type:"A"

Comment: A more generic approach would be *not sharing any assembly between client&server* .... Server respondes with a json (without those `$type`s) and client should decide how to handle that json. This is the common case when you use Google/Twitter/Facebook/Instagram etc. APIs

Comment: I agree with you but Enterprise Service Bus of my company works typed always and I could not change it :(, so I have to change $type , Is there any way to change it?

Comment: (at client side)read the json make the changes and then use it...

Comment: I think I could not explain, when ESB try to deserialize Json data it throws exception, "could not find B Type and convert instance as "object" and throw "object Must Implement IConvertible" exception."

Comment: Use a custom `SerializationBinder` as explained in [Using a custom type discriminator to tell JSON.net which type of a class hierarchy to deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099466/using-a-custom-type-discriminator-to-tell-json-net-which-type-of-a-class-hierarc/12203624#12203624).  See also [JsonConverter how to deserialize to generic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325664/jsonconverter-how-to-deserialize-to-generic-object/35349393#35349393).

Comment: Sanitizing your types with a custom `SerializationBinder` when deserializing is recommended practice, by the way.  From the [docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm): *TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than TypeNameHandling.None.*

Comment: When I saw dbc comment I recognize that my answer is duplicated, Thx dbc. It seems I could not find  true keywords when I was searching answers. I'm closing my question with duplicate info.